# Garbage collection options for Symfony Doctrine filesystem cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine

I'm using the `FilesystemCache` from Doctrine in Symfony 3, as per https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html#main

While it does support cache expiry, there does not appear to be any in built support for deleting expired items which have not been accessed (i.e. garbage collection), nor for preventing the cache from consuming all disk space.

I suppose I will need to write a cron job to a) delete all expired cache items and b) delete some non-expired cache items if disk space is low.

Is there a ready-made solution for this, or do I need to write it from scratch?

Comment: There already is a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21764) for exactly this functionality